# Streaming audio file to another computer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

This is what I am trying to do. We are 5 people in a room. Everybody has a PC. Each PC has mp3 files but only **one of the PCs has speakers** (ex. called Speakers-PC). So, instead of asking the person on Speakers-PC to play you a song you want, I was thinking of ***an application that can take an audio file from a No-Speakers-PC and send it to the Speakers-PC. The Speakers-PC can then play the audio file.*** Of course, if multiple files are sent, the application on Speakers-PC will have a queue.

So, is it worth digging or it will be just better if we buy wireless speakers and rotate the transmitter (instead we are now rotating the speakers) :)

Any ideas on how to implement something like this? I am familiar mostly with .NET technologies.

Any broad or specific help would be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,
Kiril

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many media players come with web interfaces already.  One of the winamp ones, for example, is http://www.winamp.com/plugins/details/92511

Answer (score 2):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html) is the swiss army knife of media streaming, [take a peek at the extensive feature set](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) :)

Answer (score 0):

I quick thought.
I assume the "speakers-PC" use winamp. If so then create some playlist file and load it with winamp. Also everyone of you should share your folders containing mp3 files so that "speakers-PC" could have access to them. From this point you have two options:
 1. Everyone who wants to add his own song to a playlist opens it in any text editor and adds a new line at the bottom of the file.
 2. You could create a simple web app to manage this same playlist file. You know .NET, rignt?

I haven't checked if winamp locks playlist file it currently plays. If it does then this idea is not worth a penny.

Here is basic structure of playlis file discussed.
http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?threadid=65772
I'm sure you can find in google

Good luck